# how does one *properly* secure SFTP access on an ubuntu server?

Tags: security, sftp

i need a bit of help configuring a very reliable sftpd service on an ubuntu / kubuntu 22.04 server. the ssh / tls security details are very murky to me. certbot won't be of help, and i suspect letsencrypt won't be either.

but as to the password for the ftp account itself (always a weak point, it seems), i have the following in mind :

use the Filezilla app (available on windows and linux) to access the FTP server. write down a passphrase that includes mixed lower case and uppercase special characters like ( ) , . ; - _

make sure the passphrase itself can be leet-speaked at the initial-word-character level, so have a word that starts with 'a' in there so you can assume to have the option of replacing that character with a '4'. same for 'e' = '3', and the rest of the leet-speak dictionary.

include ascii-art in the final password, as a one-liner.

secure filezilla upon installation with a password for it's password manager.

setup that password as first-letters only from the pass phrase you just designed.

repeat this process for the password of any bookmark you have in filezilla.

write down all sites, usernames, passphrases and passwords on a piece of paper that you carry somewhere on your person at all times (but not in your wallet). do not keep them in a file on any system.

i'm wondering if this process is enough to keep out people who have access to spyware and rootkit software (which i hear is available through the darkweb these days).

Answer (score 1):

What you are asking here is unclear, but it seems to be very confused and not great from a security POV.  Leet Speak does not add significant security and writing down passwords is not great from a security POV.

SFTP is Secure FTP, which runs over SSH which makes it possible to secure quite well.

In order to work with this in a secure way you really need to get to grips with the idea of private/public keys (which are well supported by SSH).  The idea is that you have 2 keys, a private key which only you know, and a public key which you can tell everyone.    People wanting to give you access to their resources add your public key to the server.  You can then use your private key in your client to access the site.  (You can't deduce the private key from the public key).

SSH (and most similar systems allow you to take this a step further by then encrypting your private key with a passphrase (ie a long password), so even if someone does get it, they can't use it without knowing your password as well.

From your point of view (and simplifying a lot), all you need to know about TLS is that it is like HTTPS - in this case all its doing is preventing a third party to intercept the connection by using a third party you/your software trusts to verify the remote side.

The idea of a password manager is a good one.  You come up with 1 complex passphrase, **use that to generate different random passwords** for each site.  Provided the passphrase you use is secure enough, you can share the file your password manager uses among devices you trust, and only remember 1 password, while having different passwords for all your sites - so if 1 is compromised it does not help the attacker get into others.

None of this will protect against people who can get access to the systems you use to enter your passwords.   (It likely does not help you with SFTP, but this is where 2FA comes into play - eg using a phone or secondary device so double verify your password.   It may be possible to tie SFTP in with 2FA depending on your server implentation, but there is a very steep learning curve from where you are to there, so its not practical)

Comment: you're assuming that my systems are secure.
they're not, due to global peace activism work that i'm involved in.
so i can not trust private key files nor any electronic storage device. see my pseudonym account at https://facebook. com/gavanHoverswell

Comment: and i'm not confused. ;) just unclear on what SFTP server software to use and how to config it.

Comment: and paper stored passwords are much more secure than any cloud hosted or digitally stored passwords, regardless of password managers or whatever "shield" you put in front of it ;) at least in my case, with the eyes everywhere factor enabled on all of my accounts, it *is*. of course, you do need to change them occasionally (once per 2 weeks to a month or so), and make sure you keep your notes secret (stored outside your wallet but on your person at all times) and note the date and time of creation as well.

Comment: your idea to use pure random passwords for the sites that get connected to, is a good one. :)

Comment: I think you have an XY problem.  You cant securely communicate if you cant secure the devices you are communicating between. Writing down passwords on paper wont fix that. If you cant trust a **passphrase encrypted** private key file you cant trust any communication....

Comment: Something like Yubikey you always keep on you could be a better alternative to paper - it cant be photocopied...  If you are serious about having some security (realustically a limited blast radius if your end device cant be trusted)  you need 2fa.

Comment: For sftp server, why not just use the sftp functionality built in to openssh ?